# What could be causing Rails migration to fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
OS: Ubuntu 14.04
Rails: 3.2.18
Ruby: 2.15
```

I inherited a Rails application, and I am having some issues with the migration.

When I try to run the latest migration, I get the following error message:

```
==  CreateBillingComments: migrating ==========================================
-- create_table(:billing_comments, {:id=>false})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Table 'billing_comments' already exists: 
CREATE TABLE `billing_comments`
```

The table billing_comments does exist, but the problem is that I cannot find the string billing_comments anywhere in any of the source code files (and that include migration files, views, controller, models, etc.).

The table is not being used, so I would like to erase it, and all references to it in the code. My concern is that if I simply delete the table, I will only have partially solved the problem.

I also looked for CreateBillingComments, to no avail.

Running rake db:schema:dump produced a new schema.rb, with the following in it:

```
create_table "billing_comments", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "ticket_id"
  t.text     "content"
  t.string   "user_id"
  t.string   "slug"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end
```

But this is the only place now where billing_comments appears.

Where could this information coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some point in your database's history the `billing_comments` table was created, by a Rails migration or otherwise. You can simply add a guard to your migration to prevent recreating the table if it already exists:

```
unless table_exists? :billing_comments
  create_table(:billing_comments, {:id=>false})
end
```

Note that you may still need to remove the `id` column  if it's already present in your `billing_comments` table.

Comment: The migration file for this table does not exist. I've already looked for it in the source and I cannot find it

Comment: Ok, shouldn't matter though, it's possible that a migration once existed and was deleted or not committed to the source. Either way the table got there somehow. You can skip recreating the table by using a guard `unless table_exists? :billing_comments` as in my answer above.

Comment: Also, how many migrations do you have? Is `billing_comments` at least in your `schema.rb`?

Comment: No, it is not in schema.rb. I searched all the files. I am using RubyMine and it allows me to do a global search traversing the entire directories structure

Comment: By guard, you mean a migration file?

Comment: No, by guard I simply mean an `if/unless` condition that prevents an action.

Comment: Is this a legacy DB? Is it local only? It's very important to have a schema.rb that's consistent with the database. I'd commit `schema.rb` to source and `rake db:schema:dump` to regenerate your schema.rb so it's consistent.

Comment: db:schema:dump produced a new schema.rb with billing_comments in it. Please see edits to my question. Still no billing_comments anywhere else in the source code.

Comment: That makes sense. Remember, when you run `rake db:schema:dump` Rails infers `schema.rb` from the structure of your existing database, it has nothing to do with your Ruby code.